# Trying to get card visual to display nothing instead of Blank

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Card visual on my page, showing the total tax amount. It currently says (Blank) when there is no value to display.

Instead of Blank, I would like it to display nothing. I tried applying the following measures to the Card View as a filter:

```
Replace Blank With Nothing = IF(ISBLANK(SUM ( YearlySales[Taxes] )),"",SUM ( YearlySales[Taxes] ))

Replace Blank With Nothing = IF((ISBLANK(SUM ( YearlySales[Taxes] )) || (SUM ( YearlySales[Taxes] ) = 0)),"",SUM ( YearlySales[Taxes] ))
```

But it still says Blank when there is nothing to display.

More details:

The card is straightforward. It shows a single number. Under Visualizations, Fields, there's only a single Field: Taxes from the YearlySales table. That's it.

Under filters, there's Taxes (went there by default and it's set to all), in addition to the measure.

Any suggestions?

## Solution:

I am new to PowerBI and DAX. I was adding the measure to the filters, instead of adding it to the Fields list. When I added it to the Fields list, it worked fine

Comment: There is something else going on in your model, because your approach with "" works fine (I use it all the time). If you can share a mock-up pbix that reproduces the problem,  I'll take a look.

Comment: I can't share this publicly, but I edited my question for more clarity. Does it work for you, when there are additional filters applied?

Comment: I don't understand your 'details'. I am assuming that you are putting the measure "Replace Blank With Nothing" on the card, is this correct?

Comment: I was trying to use it as a filter, instead of putting it in the values field